# XPFix.res file blocks TwwDateTimePicker navigation buttons

Tags: delphi-6

I have a problem with XPFix.res
In the project I use TwwDBDateTimePicker from IPControls palette
XPFix.res is mandatory because provides 3D effect on the controls
This XPFix.res blocks the navigation arrows (left and right arrows) to select Months and years
Does anyone fight with this problem ?